# Java parse a Sting with letters and numbers for an Integer

Tags: java, string, int

I'm working with  data that is a String followed by spaces and then a numeric value.

```
ncols         10812
nrows         10812
xllcorner     -107.0005555556
yllcorner     36.99944444444
cellsize      9.2592592593e-05
```

I'm trying to just read in just the numeric value. I know that from going to String to Integer or Double I can use the standard type conversions.

```
Integer.valueOf(stringOfInteger);
Double.valueOf(stringOfDouble);
```

In order to get just the numeric value I tried this as a test:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
String line = br.readLine();
line.replace("[a-z]","");
line.replace(" ","");
System.out.println(line);
```

and it output `ncols         10812`

I'm also worried about reading the cellsize value as it has an exponential.

Comment: (1) `replace` doesn't use regex, `replaceAll` does. (2) Strings are immutable, result of `replace` is not affecting original string, but returning new one with replaced content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for each line:

```
...
String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
String name = fields[0];
float value = Float.parseFloat(fields[1]);
...
```

This code will split each line in fields using the spaces as a separator. The first field is a `String` so you can use it directly (or ignore it). The second one is a `Float` value so you have to convert it before using it. You can use `Double` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. One of these days I should actually sit down and learn regular expressions.

Comment: You're welcome! Regular expressions changed my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // split each line based on spaces
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        //first word is name
        String name = words[0];
        // next word is actual number
        Double value = Double.valueOf(words[1]);
        System.out.println(name + ":" + value);
    }
    // don't forget to close the stream
    br.close();
```

Output:

```
    ncols:10812.0
    nrows:10812.0
    xllcorner:-107.0005555556
    yllcorner:36.99944444444
    cellsize:9.2592592593E-5
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want all the numeric values do a split on the space and the second item will contain  your numeric value. Then you can do any conversions as needed and not have to worry about removing any exponents.

```
String[] data = new line.split(" ");
//remove all the spaces from the second array for your data
data[1] = data[1].replaceAll("\\s", "");
//parse to whatever you need data[1] to be
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split` function in `Java` as follows:

```
String [] dataArr = data.split("[ \t]+"); //assumes @data is you data string variable name
```

The `dataArr`, then, will look like this:

```
dataArr[0] =  "ncols"
dataArr[1] =  "10812"
dataArr[2] =  "nrows"
dataArr[3] =  "10812"
.
.
.

dataArr[n - 1] = "9.2592592593e-05"   // @n is the size of the array
```

You could, then, use the `Integer.parseInt(String str)` to parse your numerical data into integers.